# Ngrx-effect doesn't sending payload in action on iOS

Tags: ios, angular, ionic-framework, ngrx, ngrx-effects

For some time I have been trying to find a solution to my problem, however, nothing has worked so far. I'm working on Ionic 4 application with Angular 8 and Ngrx. I created @Effect that calling a service which calling http service and then I need to dispatch two actions. One of them have a payload also.
Everything working fine in development (browsers). I've tried on Chrome, Firefox, Safari. Problem is appearing when I'm trying on the iPhone. On the iPhone payload sending to action is empty object `{}` instead of object with proper fields.

I've tried to build in non-production mode, disabling aot, build-optimizer, optimization.

Store init:

```
StoreModule.forFeature('rental', reducer),
EffectsModule.forFeature([RentalServiceEffect]),
```

Store:

```
export interface Contract {
    address: string;
    identity: string;
    endRentSignature?: string;
}

export interface RentalStoreState {
    status: RentStatus;
    contract?: Contract;
    metadata?: RentalMetadata;
    summary?: RentalSummary;
    carState?: CarState;
}

export const initialState: RentalStoreState = {
    status: RentStatus.NOT_STARTED,
    contract: {
        address: null,
        identity: null,
        endRentSignature: null,
    },
};
```

Action:

```
export const rentVerified = createAction(
    '[RENTAL] RENT_VERIFIED',
    (payload: Contract) => ({ payload })
);
```

Reducer:

```
const rentalReducer = createReducer(
    initialState,
    on(RentActions.rentVerified, (state, { payload }) => ({
        ...state,
        contract: payload,
        status: RentStatus.RENT_VERIFIED
    })));

export function reducer(state: RentalStoreState | undefined, action: Action) {
    return rentalReducer(state, action);
}
```

Method from a service:

```
   public startRentalProcedure(
        vehicle: Vehicle,
        loading: any
    ): Observable<IRentalStartResponse> {
        loading.present();

        return new Observable(observe => {
            const id = '';
            const key = this.walletService.getActiveAccountId();

            this.fleetNodeSrv
                .startRent(id, key, vehicle.id)
                .subscribe(
                    res => {
                        loading.dismiss();
                        observe.next(res);
                        observe.complete();
                    },
                    err => {
                        loading.dismiss();
                        observe.error(err);
                        observe.complete();
                    }
                );
        });
    }
```

Problematic effect:

```
@Effect()
public startRentalProcedure$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(RentalActions.startRentVerifying),
    switchMap(action => {
        return this.rentalSrv
            .startRentalProcedure(action.vehicle, action.loading)
            .pipe(
                mergeMap(response => {
                    return [
                            RentalActions.rentVerified({
                                address: response.address,
                                identity: response.identity
                            }),
                            MainActions.rentalProcedureStarted()
                        ];
                    }),
                    catchError(err => {
                        this.showConfirmationError(err);
                        return of({ type: '[RENTAL] START_RENTAL_FAILED' });
                    })
                );
        })
    );
```